# how to preserve variable value when post back occurring

Tags: c#, asp.net

i used static variable to hold photo name and sign name and i passed these name to one page to another page through query string these work fine when i am run it in local system but when i am run it from server system and access through multiple client system and when redirect from one page to another page then there is photo name and sign name are same for all client system.

and when i m create a simple variable(not static) then it lost its value at the time of post back of page.

please give me solution for these how can i solve it

Comment: Could you give us a code sample? Also is this webforms, MVC, WebAPI etc?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) instead of static variables. Sessions are unique for users while static variables are shared among all the objects.

> ASP.NET session state enables you to store and retrieve values for a
>   user as the user navigates ASP.NET pages in a Web application. HTTP is
>   a stateless protocol. This means that a Web server treats each HTTP
>   request for a page as an independent request. The server retains no
>   knowledge of variable values that were used during previous requests.
>   ASP.NET session state identifies requests from the same browser during
>   a limited time window as a session, and provides a way to persist
>   variable values for the duration of that session.

As a addition not If static members are being access by multiple thread then they must be considered for thread safety. This article give explanation of [static members thread safety](http://odetocode.com/Articles/313.aspx).

Comment: in my project i upload 30 files and for these i used static variable. so if i used session instead of static variable so i will need to use 30 session variable for this task ?

Comment: You can use List<T> store it in Session, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET, static variables are shared among all users as they are served by the same AppDomain in the w3wp-Process. When debugging the application on your development machine, you are the only user so you don't observe the same behavior.

Instead of using static variables, store the value in Session memory, e.g.:

```
Session["MySessionKey"] = variableValueThatYouWantToPreserve;
```

You can retrieve the value later on by reading from Session memory, e.g.:

```
var preservedValue = (PreservedValueType) Session["MySessionKey"];
```

For details on how to use Session memory, see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

If you transfer the value in a Request parameter when you access a new page and only need to preserve it on page-level, you can also use [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) to preserve the value between PostBacks to the page.

Comment: in my project i upload 30 files and for these i used static variable. so if i used session instead of static variable so i will need to use 30 session variable for this task ?

Comment: @chitrakantsahu: why don't you store the files in a database (or alternatively a file system folder) right away? I assume that the 30 files consume a lot of memory (per user) so it would be good to store them as soon as possible so that the memory consumption on the web server is reduced and you can serve more users.